# grepping a not matching pattern with a pattern file and data from a pipe

Tags: grep, cygwin

I have an ignore.txt file:

```
cat ignore.txt
clint
```

when I do:

```
pip freeze | grep -v -f ignore.txt
```

I get:

```
GitPython==0.3.2.RC1  
Markdown==2.2.1  
async==0.6.1  
clint==0.3.1  
gitdb==0.5.4  
legit==0.1.1  
push-to-wordpress==0.1  
python-wordpress-xmlrpc==2.2  
smmap==0.8.2
```

but when I do:

```
pip freeze | grep -v clint
```

I do get the correct output:

```
GitPython==0.3.2.RC1
Markdown==2.2.1
async==0.6.1
gitdb==0.5.4
legit==0.1.1
push-to-wordpress==0.1
python-wordpress-xmlrpc==2.2
smmap==0.8.2
```

How can I achieve that with grep and command line tools?

**Clarfication Edit:** I use windows with cygwin so I believe this is GNU grep 2.6.3 (from grep --version)

Comment: in your ignore.txt, does the `clint` have leading/trailing spaces? In your example there is leading space.

Comment: Which operating system and grep version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax looks correct and works on my system.
There may be a problem with your `ignore.txt` file.
In particular, check that:

- there are no leading or trailing spaces, tabs and the like around the word you are trying to filter (as suggested by Kent above)
- the file has Unix line endings
- the file is terminated by a single newline

About the latter, the [Single Unix Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) says:

> Patterns in *pattern_file* shall be terminated by a `<newline>`.

Which means that a file with no terminator, or with a different terminator (e.g. CR LF), might behave unexpectedly (though that might be system-dependent).